# Prevent use of pre ANSI-92 old syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder if there's a way to prevent the creation of objects that contain old ansi sintax of join, maybe server triggers, can anyone help me?

Comment: As long as Sql-Server compiler compiles the code successfully, and user has permission to create objects, it will allow the users to create objects using any code. I think what you can do is ask your HR dept to send an email around ,"Anyone who uses ANSI-92 syntax will be sacked", this will work better then any other DDL triggers or motivational speeches :)

Comment: lol, that would work, except that my boss still uses that syntax... That's meant to block third party updates that still have this syntax.

Comment: Well they say the BOSS is always right, if he is doing let him/her. :)

Comment: actually it's a She! But yeah there's nothing I can do about this, I can only enforce third party developers, and other local developers.

Comment: Why?  Seems a matter of preference, and there's clearly no corporate standard since your boss is using the older syntax.  I'd be more worried about people wasting time rooting out valid, functional code rather than the people writing the valid, functional code to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [DDL trigger](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and mine the eventdata() XML for the content of the proc. If you can detect the old syntax using some fancy string-parsing functions (maybe looking for commas between known table names or looking for `*=` or `=*`), then you can roll back the creation of the proc or function.

Comment: I was kind of looking for that magical string search pattern, lol

Comment: If you are using a database compatibility level of greater than 80, the "\*=" and "=\*" outer join syntax is already disabled, but sorry I don't know of any magical pattern for stopping the old inner join syntax.  It would be really tough to implement anything in a DDL trigger using native T-SQL string functions.

Comment: I'm running SQL 2008 R2 with 80 compatibility for almost all databases

Answer (score 1):

First reaction - code reviews and a decent QA process!

I've had some success looking at [`sys.syscomments.text`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186293.aspx).  A simple `where text like '%*=%'` should do.  Be aware that long SQL strings may be split across multiple rows.  I realise this won't prevent objects getting in there in the first place.  But then DDL triggers won't tell you how big your current problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Although I fully understand your effort, I believe that this type of actions is the wrong way of getting where you want. First of all, you might get into serious trouble with your boss and, depending of where you work, get fired.

Second, as stated before, doing code reviews, explaining why the old syntax sucks. You have to have a decent reason why one should avoid the *= stuff. 'Because you don't like it' is not a feasible argument.  In fact, there are quite some articles around showing that certain problems are just not solvable using this type of syntax.

Third, you might want to point out that separating conditions into grouping (`JOIN ... ON...`) and filtering conditions (`WHERE...`) increases the readability and might therefore be an options.

Collect your arguments and convince your colleagues rather than punishing them in quite an arrogant way.